# SQL Server 2005 Finding the user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 How to Find the user who has all books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798710/sql-server-2005-how-to-find-the-user-who-has-all-books)

I have a question about sql query.

I am trying to make the query that user who has all computer book. 
For example, 
I have two tables,

1) Item table

```
|itemid |item_name          |

|1      | computerbook1     |

|2      | computerbook2     |

|3      | computerbook3     |

|4      | mathbook1         |

|5      | mathbook2         |

|6      | physicsbook       |
```

2) userinventory table

```
|used_id | name_item        |

|1       | computerbook1    |

|1       | computerbook2    |

|1       | computerbook3    |

|2       | computerbook1    |

|2       | mathbook1        |

|2       | physicsbook      |

|3       | computerbook1    |

|3       | computerbook3    |
```

Since user "1" has all of computer book, I would like make query that returning the user 1.

What I did was...

```
Create Table #tmp (
    Classname [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT DISTINCT item_name  
FROM ITEM
WHERE item_name  like 'computerbook%'
```

I would like to compare to find user who has all of item..

However, I am not really sure how to do it.. because I can not use **count** or any aggression

Do not use "count"

Does anyway know they way to find user id who has all of computerbook?

Comment: Voting to close: the OP asked exactly the same question again later, and the later version has attracted more answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798710/sql-server-2005-how-to-find-the-user-who-has-all-books

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that will just get you the users who have all items in the computerbook category (assuming that `item.itemname` is unique).

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM userinventory u
INNER JOIN item i ON u.name_item=i.item_name
    AND u.name_item LIKE 'computer%'
GROUP BY USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(item_name) = (
    SELECT COUNT(item_name)
    FROM item
    WHERE item_name LIKE 'computer%'
)
```

You can obviously adjust it to fit whatever item category you want.

Are you trying to do this for every category in the `item` table?  If so, that will be a little more involved, but is possible.

Comment: thank you for answer, but I cannot use the COUNT. Do you know how I make the query without *COUNT*??

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and thought you were having problems when using count.  Not that you _can't_ use count.  Why is it that you can't use count?

Comment: it is the system requirement.

Comment: Ok, so aggregations are out as well which means you can't use SUM either.  You tagged this mysql AND sql server.  Does the solution have to work for both then?

Comment: sorry, I mean just mssql, and I cannot use SUM either.